# VSCode incorrectly inserting semi-colons in React Typescript project when formatting on save with Prettier

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I am working with React and Typescript in VSCode, using Prettier as the default formatter. Inside my `~/.vscode/settings.json`, I have it set to format the document on save:

```json
{
  "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules\\typescript\\lib",
  "cmake.configureOnOpen": false,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modifications",

  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true,
    "source.organizeImports": true,
    "source.sortMembers": true
  }
}
```

This worked for a long time without issue, however for some reason, maybe a bug, lately I have been experiencing the insertion of semi-colons in nonsensical locations, for instance following a callback block passed into the argument of UseCallback. Curiously, on the first save it will just move the dependency array to the next line, but on subsequent saves it adds the semicolon:

- *Initial format*

```
const myCallback = useCallback(() => {
  return myDependency1 + myDependency2 + myDependency3 + myDependency4 > 0;
},[myDependency1, myDependency2, myDependency3, myDependency4])
```

- *Following one save*

```
const myCallback = useCallback(() => {
  return myDependency1 + myDependency2 + myDependency3 + myDependency4 > 0;
},
[myDependency1, myDependency2, myDependency3, myDependency4])
```

- *Following second save*

```
const myCallback = useCallback(() => {
  return myDependency1 + myDependency2 + myDependency3 + myDependency4 > 0;
};,
[myDependency1, myDependency2, myDependency3, myDependency4])
```

This is breaking the code as it is an illegal character so I am having to set `"editor.formatOnSave": false` to prevent this happening which is not ideal.

What is strange is that I can *Ctrl+Shift+P* > *Format Document* or *Format Document with...* then selecting Prettier - and the file is fixed without adding the problematic semicolons.

I have also tried using `// prettier-ignore` and `//eslint-disable-next-line` but this is not changing the behaviour.

Perhaps that this is a bug pushed to the Prettier extension, VSCode, or another extension or library (ESLint perhaps?) - though I can't find the issue listed on any of these project on GitHub. Therefore my real question is what can I do to figure out what is causing this so I can report it to the correct project or perhaps just fix whatever misconfiguration I have made?

Comment: Just FWIW, I can't replicate this. It doesn't look like the extension has been updated in over two months.   What versions are you using? I'm using `esbenp.prettier-vscode.` v9.9.0, Prettier v2.8.0, and VS Code v1.73.1 More from Help | About: Version 1.73.1⏎ Commit: 6261075646f055b99068d3688932416f2346dd3b⏎ Date: 2022-11-09T03:54:53.913Z⏎ Electron: 19.0.17⏎ Chromium: 102.0.5005.167⏎ Node.js: 16.14.2⏎ V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0⏎ OS: Linux x64 5.8.0-29-generic⏎ Sandboxed: No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a bug](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/12964) in Prettier.

Either change `formatOnSaveMode` to be `"file"` or upgrade to a Prettier version greater or equal to 2.8